# Looking for a or the term for a vector who is parallel to an axis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm looking for a term for a vector who is parallel to a x- or y-axis. Is there a name for such a vector?

For example: $\vec{AB}$ while $A = (10, 2)$ and $B = (15, 2)$

This vector is parallel to the y-axis. Does a name or a term for this kind of vectors exists?

Comment: I think affine might be appropriate, since it is in the same direction just with the origin translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the term *along*:

> Vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is along the *x*-axis

Answer (score 1):

It's called A normal vector (with respect to an axis or another vector).
A normal vector to the x-axis is parallel to the y-axis, for example.

You can also talk about standard basis vectors. 
$e_1=(1,0)$ is parallel to the x-axis.